# Inspect numbers in a integer?

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way to determine how much even numbers are in a number ?
Let's say you have 4754 number or if we let the user make input of any number he wants.
How can I find how many even numbers are in a number ?
For 4754 number should be two numbers and they are two 4.

Talking about simple integers, in this example int a = 4754;

Ty all for quick reply's.
This is what I got from Tim code, and it's working.

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your number: ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int even = number.ToString().Count(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()) % 2 == 0);
        Console.WriteLine("We have {0} even numbers in a number.", even);
```

Comment: By numbers you mean digits of course..

Comment: You should post **code you wrote** so we can start from that and we'll all save time...

Answer (score 2):

You could convert them to string and use LINQ:

```
int countEven = 47543.ToString().Count(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()) % 2 == 0); // 2
int countOdd  = 47543.ToString().Count(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()) % 2 == 1); // 3
```

( i have used `47543` since it's a more meaningful sample )

Comment: Great for clarity, but the performance suffers badly from the two ToString().

Comment: @Steve: there's certainly room for improvement. However, `47543.ToString()` and `char.ToString()` are definitely not a problem (as opposed to the `int.Parse` which could be inefficient).

Comment: yeah "1234".ToString() takes 2 hours to execute on my machine

Answer (score 1):

My approach (essentially the same as @Steve's, but with slightly different logic):

```
public static int CountEvenDigits(int number)
{
    int nEven = 0;

    while (number > 0)
    {
        if ((number & 1) == 0)
            ++nEven;

        number /= 10;
    }

    return nEven;
}
```

Comment: I am convinced that your solution is better for performance, but the results are the same with a ten millions loop. 30 ms...

Comment: @Steve Yeah, it's really not significant.

Answer (score 0):

Using a traditional approach

```
void Main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int theNum = 475436;
    while(theNum > 0)
    {
        int test = theNum - ((theNum / 10) * 10);
        if(test % 2 == 0) 
            count++;
        theNum = theNum / 10;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string num = n.ToString();
for(int i =0;i < num.Length;i++){
    if(int.Parse(num[i]) % 2 == 0)
    Console.WriteLine(num[i]);
}
```

Sorry for my previous answer,I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Maybe OP is asking about count of even **digits** (from his question: _"For 4754 number should be two numbers and they are two 4."_).

Comment: It says numbers,that's why I got a bit confused about what he meant.Right.

Answer (score 0):

Tim provided a great answer how to do it using LINQ. Still, I think that being new to C# you should first learn how to do this using a simple loop.

You should:

1. Convert the number to string
2. Loop through each of the characters in the string
3. Convert each character back to integer
4. Calculate modulus of 2 for each integer you got. Numbers with mod equal to 0 will be even.

Try to write some code covering these steps. Use search engines to figure out the operations you are not sure about. If you get stuck somewhere, post the code here and we will help you.

Comment: @Oliver: Yes, you are right. Not sure if you read my whole post, but I mentioned Tim's answer myself. My point is that one line of condensed LINQ code might not be very easy to understand for someone asking such a basic question.

Comment: Sorry, i misread your answer. So simply ignore my comment (I already deleted it).

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (a)
{
    case 1:
        return 0;
    case 2:
        return 1;
    case 3:
        return 0;
    case 4:
        return 1;
    case 5:
        return 0;
    case 6:
        return 1;
    case 7:
        return 0;
    case 8:
        return 1;
    case 9:
        return 0;
    case 10:
        return 1;
    case 11:
        return 0;
    case 12:
        return 1;
    case 13:
        return 0;
    case 14:
        return 1;
    case 15:
        return 0;
    case 16:
        return 1;
    case 17:
        return 0;
    case 18:
        return 1;
    case 19:
        return 0;
    case 20:
        return 2;
    case 21:
        return 1;
    case 22:
        return 2;
    case 23:
        return 1;
    case 24:
        return 2;
    case 25:
        return 1;
    case 26:
        return 2;
    case 27:
        return 1;
    case 28:
        return 2;
    case 29:
        return 1;
    case 30:
        return 1;
    case 31:
        return 0;
    case 32:
        return 1;
    case 33:
        return 0;
    case 34:
        return 1;
    case 35:
        return 0;
    case 36:
        return 1;
    case 37:
        return 0;
    case 38:
        return 1;
    case 39:
        return 0;
    case 40:
        return 2;
    case 41:
        return 1;
    case 42:
        return 2;
    case 43:
        return 1;
    case 44:
        return 2;
    case 45:
        return 1;
    case 46:
        return 2;
    case 47:
        return 1;
    case 48:
        return 2;
    case 49:
        return 1;
    case 50:
        return 1;
    case 51:
        return 0;
    case 52:
        return 1;
    case 53:
        return 0;
    case 54:
        return 1;
    case 55:
        return 0;
    case 56:
        return 1;
    case 57:
        return 0;
    case 58:
        return 1;
    case 59:
        return 0;
    case 60:
        return 2;
    case 61:
        return 1;
    case 62:
        return 2;
    case 63:
        return 1;
    case 64:
        return 2;
    case 65:
        return 1;
    case 66:
        return 2;
    case 67:
        return 1;
    case 68:
        return 2;
    case 69:
        return 1;
    case 70:
        return 1;
    case 71:
        return 0;
    case 72:
        return 1;
    case 73:
        return 0;
    case 74:
        return 1;
    case 75:
        return 0;
    case 76:
        return 1;
    case 77:
        return 0;
    case 78:
        return 1;
    case 79:
        return 0;
    case 80:
        return 2;
    case 81:
        return 1;
    case 82:
        return 2;
    case 83:
        return 1;
    case 84:
        return 2;
    case 85:
        return 1;
    case 86:
        return 2;
    case 87:
        return 1;
    case 88:
        return 2;
    case 89:
        return 1;
    case 90:
        return 1;
    case 91:
        return 0;
    case 92:
        return 1;
    case 93:
        return 0;
    case 94:
        return 1;
    case 95:
        return 0;
    case 96:
        return 1;
    case 97:
        return 0;
    case 98:
        return 1;
    case 99:
        return 0;
    case 100:
        return 2;
    case 463284597:
        return 5;
    case 4754:
        return 2;
}
```

If you haven't got time to type all 2147483647 numbers or are worried about space then just include the numbers you want to support. Most users are unlikely to type obscure numbers like 1151.

Comment: What about 101 or 463284597? OP's sample number is already 4754.